# Wrong value from DropDownList, SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I get the wrong value from my Dropdownlist (ddlCity). I always get the "default" value, the value the list has when the page load. What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server"AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable CountryTable = CategoryAccess.GetCountry();
        ddlCountry.DataSource = CountryTable;
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        String CountryID = ddlCountry.SelectedValue;

        DataTable CityTable = CategoryAccess.GetCitysInCountry(CountryID);
        ddlCity.DataSource = CityTable;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "City";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityID";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = (ddlCity.SelectedItem.Value);
    //This is where id is wrong, unless I choose the first city in the list.
}
```

Database code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetCountry
AS          
SELECT        CountryID, CountryName
FROM          tblCountry  



ALTER PROCEDURE GetCitysInCountry
@CountryID INT
AS          
SELECT        tblCitysInCountry.CityID, tblCitysInCountry.CountryID, tblCity.City, tblCountry.CountryName
FROM          tblCitysInCountry LEFT JOIN
                         tblCity ON tblCitysInCountry.CityID = tblCity.CityID LEFT JOIN
                         tblCountry ON tblCitysInCountry.CountryID = tblCountry.CountryID
WHERE         (tblCitysInCountry.CountryID = @CountryID)
```

Comment: From your code comment it looks like your problem is CityID. Is this the case? Or is it CountryID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` occurs before the selected index is set during postback. Try moving your second set of databinding code to a more appropriate place - maybe in the event handler that `ddlCountry` will be invoking ([`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx)?)

---

There certainly seem to be a lot of hits on Google for "[page_load SelectedValue](http://www.google.com/search?q=page_load%20selectedvalue)", which all tend to indicate the value cannot be accessed during `Page_Load`.

Comment: Understanding the page lifecycle will make you a MUCH happier (and more effective) asp.net programmer.  :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx